# Getting NameError: name 'gdbSuccessCount' is not defined?

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing

I'm using a 412-line script that gathers and merges online tile data.  However, I'm receiving a Traceback error, NameError: name 'gdbSuccessCount' is not defined.

I've included the portions of the code that gdbSuccessCount is included in (only 3 times it appears as is).

The problem is the last occurrence, in line 406 as follows:

if merge and gdbSuccessCount > 1:

Here are lines 333-412:

```
    r = 0
    if GDB:
        gdbSuccessCount = 0
        for g in gdbList:
            tileGDBID = g
            q250k = "q" + string.split(tileGDBID,"-")[0]
            srcGDB = dataPath +"/" + q250k + "/geodatabase/"+ tileGDBID +".gdb.zip"
            destGDB = dest+"\\geodatabase\\"+ tileGDBID+".gdb"
            destGDBzip = dest+"\\geodatabase\\"+ tileGDBID+".gdb.zip"
            if not os.path.exists(destGDB):
                arcpy.AddMessage("Copying Geodatabase " + tileGDBID)
                if not os.path.exists(destGDBzip):
                    try:
                        urllib.urlretrieve(srcGDB, destGDBzip)
                        gdbSuccessCount += 1
                    except:
                        arcpy.AddMessage("\t WARNING: Geodatabase for tile " + tileGDBID + " not found - moving on to next one...") 
                if os.path.exists(destGDBzip):
                    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(destGDBzip)
                    zf.extractall(dest+"\\geodatabase")
                    del zf
                    os.remove(destGDBzip)
            else:
                arcpy.AddMessage("\tGeodatabase " + tileGDBID + " exists, moving on to next tile...")

    if LAS:
        # this is a batch file that will be used to unzip the LAZ files....
        f1 = open(dest + "\\las\\unziplaz.bat", "w")
        # now go through the list and download the LAZ files...
        lasSuccessCount = 0
        for l in lasList:
            q250k = "q" + string.split(l,"-")[0]        
            srcLAZ = dataPath + "/" + q250k + "/laz/"+ l +".laz"
            destLAZ = dest + "\\las\\"+ l +".laz"
            destLAS = dest + "\\las\\"+ l + ".las"
            if not os.path.exists(destLAZ):
                arcpy.AddMessage("Copying LAZ " + destLAZ + "\n")
                try:
                    urllib.urlretrieve(srcLAZ, destLAZ)
                    lasSuccessCount += 1
                except:
                    arcpy.AddMessage("\t WARNING: LAZ file for tile " + srcLAZ + " not found - moving on to next one...")                
            if not os.path.exists(destLAS) and os.path.exists(destLAZ):
                f1.write(dest + "\\las\\laszip.exe -v -i " + destLAZ + " -o " + destLAS + "\n")

        #close the batch file    
        f1.close()
        if lasSuccessCount > 0:
            # add a message telling the user what we are doing...
            arcpy.AddMessage("Unzipping LAZ Files....please be patient")
            # download LASZIP.EXE from the mngeo site...
            lazsrc = "ftp://ftp.lmic.state.mn.us/pub/data/elevation/lidar/tools/lastools/laszip.exe"
            lazdest = dest + "\\las\\laszip.exe"
            urllib.urlretrieve(lazsrc,lazdest)

            #call the batch file to unzip the LAZ files...
            os.system(dest + "\\las\\unziplaz.bat")

            # if the user has ArcGIS 10.1 then build a LAS dataset.    
            if arcpy.GetInstallInfo()['Version'] == '10.2.2':
                lasDName = dest + "\\" + "las_data.lasd"
                if not os.path.exists(lasDName):
                    arcpy.AddMessage("Creating LAS Dataset - " + lasDName)
                    try:
                        arcpy.CreateLasDataset_management(dest+"\\las",lasDName,"NO_RECURSION","#","#","COMPUTE_STATS","RELATIVE_PATHS")
                    except:
                        arcpy.AddWarning("LAS files downloaded but attempt to bring into LAS dataset failed...")
                else:
                    arcpy.AddMessage("LAS Dataset - " + lasDName + " found....")
        else:
            arcpy.AddWarning("No LAS files found in requested area....")

    # if the user wants to merge the downloaded data then do that now....
    if merge and gdbSuccessCount > 1:
        arcpy.AddMessage("Merging tiles to "+ dest + "\\ELEVATION_DATA.GDB")
        merge_tiles(dest)
    elif gdbCount == 1:
        arcpy.AddMessage("Only one GDB found...no merging necessary")
    elif gdbCount == 0:
        arcpy.AddWarning("No Geodatabase Tiles found in area requested....")
```

Comment: Was your problem solved by formatting? 
FYI, PyScripter is a good IDE to work in that can help with your formatting issues.

Comment: Adjusting the formatting did not help.  I received the same error.

Comment: It looks like gdbSuccessCount is defined within the "if GDB" block so it may not be initialized when you get to the "if merge and..." statement.

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be that you are defining gdbSuccessCount inside of a conditional statement

```
  if GDB:
    gdbSuccessCount = 0
```

By doing so, if GDB evaluates to false and you keep moving down the script, the variable name gdbSuccessCount will not be set. When you get down to the line if merge and gdbSuccessCount > 1:, the variable gdbSuccessCount has not been set and thus you get the Name Error.

Comment: I altered the script by relocating gdbSuccessCount = 0 above if GDB: but I still receive the same error.

Comment: What is the difference between gdbSuccessCount and gdbCount? Where are you first setting gdbCount?

Comment: I believe gdbSuccessCount is meant to be the number of geodatabases whose tiles are successfully copied into the new single gdb.  I also believe gdbCount is the total number of geodatabases from which these tiles are coming.  I have also posted my issue to its makers forum but it is unmanaged and offers little support.